# How to customize Jackson XML parse in reactive WebClient?

Tags: java, jackson, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'm using `WebClient` from `spring-webflux` to send `POST` requests. I also have the `jackson` library on classpath.

Question: how can I tell the default jackson mapper to try parsing just *any* content as `application/xml`. I could not find any configuration method where I could change the xml decoder in any way!?

```
this.webClient = WebClient.builder()
                    .baseUrl("/")
                    .defaultHeader(...)
                    .filter(logRequest())
                    .filter(logResponse())
                    .build();
```

Where could I configure the xml parsing?

Sidenote:
When using `RestTemplate` I had a the following bean that automatically provided that feature:

```
    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(
            Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = builder
                .createXmlMapper(true)
                .build();

        MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(mapper);
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(
            MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,
            MediaType.TEXT_HTML));

        return converter;
    }
```

How can I convert that for the `WebClient` usage?